# I getting below error when executing helloworld.js by using vs code editor

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below error coming after submitting the npm run test.

```
PS C:\Users\vpandey51\Exercism> npm run test

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vpandey51\Exercism\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vpandey51\Exercism\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vpandey51\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-20T06_54_27_297Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Your script is trying to read a file named `package.json`, but the file doesn't exist. What more needs to be said?

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` file is missing.

If you are creating nodejs app then first run `npm init`

When it will ask `test command`, put `node index.js` there

Then run your code `npm run test`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you always have to run a file by using `node filename.js` where filename is the name of the JavaScript file, in this case `helloworld.js`.

Second, if you use `npm run test`, it means that there has to be a `package.json` located in your Project directory, and a script named `test` in the `scripts` object of the package.json should be present. Looks like package.json isn't in there.